# Count in each row the number of second column

Tags: sql

Here is answer to request

[image]

The question is how to count by each selected_date e.x:

1. 2012-02-10: 1
2. 2012-02-15: 0
3. 2012-02-14: 3
4. 2012-02-11: 0

How to make this request

Here is the request to get above answer

```
 select selected_date, date1 from 
(select selected_date from 
       (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
       (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
        (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
        (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
         (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
         (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2012-02-10' and '2012-02-15' ) vv left join clicker on clicker.date1=vv.selected_date
```

Comment: please check this to improve the question http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/spaghettidba/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: you can use {}  to format  coding sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
SELECT selected_date, SUM(CASE WHEN date1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) FROM table
GROUP BY selected_date
```

Answer (score 0):

So , basically this?

```
SELECT t.selected_date, COUNT(t.date1)
FROM ( Your Query Here )
GROUP BY t.selected_date
```

`COUNT()` ignores `NULL` values by default, so it will count only matches .